# Discontinuity set vs approximative discontinuity set of a function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a bounded interval. Denote by $Su$ the set of discontinuities of $u$.
On the other hand there is the term approximative discontinuity set of $u$: Assume $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. We say $z\in \mathbb{R}$ is the approximative limit of $u$ in $x\in \Omega$, if
\begin{align}
\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{1}{\rho^n}\int\limits_{B_{\rho}(x)}|u(y)-z|dy=0.
\end{align}
Then the set of the approximative discontinuity set is defined as $(Su)'=\{x\in \Omega: \text{ the last equation does not hold } \}$.
In literature for both sets $Su$ is used. Are these sets the same ? Is there an inclusion ?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should look at 'Lebesgue points' and 'Lebesgue differentiation theorem'.

Comment: At least for functions $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ , $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, I can now say, that if $x_0$ is a discontinuity point of first kind, it is not a Lebesgue point. So there are for sure not the same. What about discontinuities of second kind ? Is every Lebesgue point a point of discontinuity of second kind ? In particular how do we define the set of discontinuities for functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of subtleties might exist for functions of more than one variable, but ... Theorem 2.3 on p. 35 of Bruckner's [**Differentiation of Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821869906) (1994 edition; at end of Section 3.2 of the 1978 edition, but the paging is different): "A necessary and sufficient condition that a set $A \subset [a,b]$ be the set of points of [ordinary] continuity of an approximately continuous function $f$ is that $A$ be dense in $[a,b]$ and of type $G_{\delta}.$ When $A$ meets these conditions, $f$ can be chosen bounded and hence a derivative."

Comment: Thus, any meager (i.e. first Baire category) $F_{\sigma}$ subset can be the discontinuity set of an approximately continuous function, and such sets can be large in the sense (for example) of having Hausdorff dimension $1$ in every open interval (see **Proof B** in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/388862/15780)). A proof of the result I stated in the previous comment can also be found in [this paper](https://yadda.icm.edu.pl/baztech/element/bwmeta1.element.baztech-article-BUS1-0005-0060). (I don't know if a copy is online--I have a preliminary version sent to me in June 1997.)